# Centering text label in Java

Tags: java, css

I'm trying to center my score counter and adjust it every time it changes, but I cant get the code right.

Im using `GLabel` from `GraphicsProgram` as my label.

In theory, this should work:

```
counter.setLocation(getWidth() / 2 - counter.getWidth() / 2,
                    getHeight() / 2 - counter.getHeight() / 2);
```

but it doesn't, the counter is completely off screen. [image]

I used the trial and error method and found the right position, but it doesn't make any sense to me. Why should I add 3.2 height and not subtract half?

```
counter.setLocation(getWidth() / 2 - counter.getWidth() / 2,
                    getHeight() / 2 + counter.getHeight() / 3.2);
```

[image]

Comment: check what the value of `getWidth()` is. It might not be getting the width of the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it assuming it was `javascript` and not `java`, only to find out I jumped the gun and was wrong! Apologies! I wont be so quick on the edit button next time!

Answer (score 0):

In programming the coordinate system starts in the top left corner. This means that when you subtract from the height, the counter will go up. To make it go down, you have to add to the height.

0,0 - - - - - - -
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎|
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎|‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎‏‏‎‎‏‏‎• (6, 2)
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎|
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎|‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎‎‏‏‎‎• (6, 4)
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎|
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎